# Sed : Delete between the first n lines the ones with a given string in them

Tags: bash, sed

I have given a string and a file. I have to delete between the first 30 lines the ones having the given string. Tried something like **`sed -i '/pattern/1,30d' filename`**   Yet it gives errors. More specifically what I want is sed to analyze only the first 30 lines, and if it finds the pattern given, to delete the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with GNU sed, it appears to be possible to do

```
sed '1,30{/pattern/d}' file
```

A scaled-down test: given `file` as

```
some line
pattern
other line
some line
pattern
other line
```

then

```
$ sed '1,3{/pattern/d}' file
some line
other line
some line
pattern
other line
```

Comment: Worked good :D now just have to quiet it and ready :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `sed` with `head` and `tail`:

```
( head -n30 file | sed '/pattern/d' ; tail -n+31 file ) > newfile
```

or, use Perl:

```
perl -i~ -ne 'print if $. > 30 or not /pattern/' file
```

Comment: Trying right now, I'll let you know, if it worked :)